# Ordered Tensoring of Operators

Tags: hamiltonian-simulation, linear-algebra

*Novice warning*: I have a strong feeling I am simply misunderstanding something fundamental!

Setup:

Classically -

1. I taken in some structured input and assign to each qubit $q_i$ in a register $Q = \{q_1, q_2,..,q_n\}$ a portion of the problem state.
2. I create $m = O(poly(n))$ hermitian operators $G_i$. Assume each $G_i$ does not have an efficient Pauli decomposition.
3. Each $G_i$ operates non-trivially on a noncontiguous subset of $Q$. Ex:
   $$
   G_5| q_3,q_7,q_n \rangle
   $$
4. For all qubits not operated on by $G_i$, there are a known collection of Pauli operators that act on those qubits.

Question:

How do I write matrix that is the result of tensoring $G_i$ with all the paulis on the "other qubits"? Naively I thought:
$$
H_5= X^2 \otimes  G_5 \otimes Y^6 \otimes Z^8...
$$
**NOTE: The superscript above indicates the qubit being operated on**

But that doesn't seem to take into account the order correctly.  In the above example, $X^2$ operates on the qubit before $G_5$ but the $Y^6$ is between the $q_3$ and $q_7$ operated on by $G_5$.

If it is at all important, eventually I will be simulating the system:
$$
e^{-i\theta\sum_{j}^{m}{H_j}}
$$

Comment: Just want to make sure that I get it right - What are the dimensions of the $G_i$ operators? On how many qubits each $G_i$ operator is being applied upon?

Comment: @Ohad:

Each $G_i$ operates on a strict subset of the $n$ qubits. The exact number is tied to the problem instance and changes with each $G_i$. If it clarifies matters, one can think of the each qubit as representing the state/partition/coloring/whatever of nodes in a graph and the $G_i$s as a state transformation derived from the graph structure / edges of the graph.

Let me know if I clarified that clearly and thanks!

Comment: I almost forgot, the dimension of the operator is the natural size from the number of qubits operated on. Using the example above, $G_5$ would be 8 by 8.

Comment: I think there are 2 options: 1. Change the order of the qubits such that it will fit and then tensor the operators in the right order. 2. Create the $G_i$ operator by tensoring single qubit gates for all qubits (Identity matrix operator for leaving qubit untouched). Then use matrix multiplication to combine operators.

Comment: I don't think (1) is actually possible in the general case. I've been trying to do (2) but have been hereto unsuccessful without using exponentially many terms. Thanks for all your help just the same!

Comment: Is decomposing $G_i$ to single-qubit gates possible? All we need is just to fill in the gaps and then you will be able to tensor $G_i$ with any other gate.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing. I didn't initially think it was possible, but having a dialogue helped. Thanks!